# Confused with fstream and pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, fstream, ifstream

I would like to write a function which takes an `fstream`, processes it, and fills information in a `struct` I supply in the second argument.

My problem is that I am confused how to use pointers and fstreams as I get debug errors:

> Access violation writing location
>   0xcccccccc.

Here is the main function:

```
int main()
{
    keyframe_struct kfstruct;

    string ifile = "filename";
    ifstream fin( ifile, ios::binary );

    load_from_keyframe_file( fin, kfstruct );
    fin.close();

    cout << kfstruct.num_keyframes << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the function I try to use for parsing the binary file and filling in the information in the struct kfstruct:

```
struct keyframe_struct
{
    int num_views;
    int num_keyframes;
    vector<keyframe> keyframes;
};

int load_from_keyframe_file( ifstream &fin, keyframe_struct &kfstruct )
{

    char keyword[100];

    while ( !fin.eof() )
    {
        fin.getline( keyword, 100, 0 );

        if ( strcmp( keyword, "views" ) == 0 )
        {
            fin.read(( char* ) kfstruct.num_views, sizeof( int ) );
        }

        else if ( strcmp( keyword, "keyframes" ) == 0 )
        {
            fin.read(( char* ) kfstruct.num_keyframes, sizeof( int ) );
        }

    }

}
```

**Can you tell me what am I doing wrong**? I'm sure I am making some huge errors here as I am just a beginner and I still don't understand clearly what should I and what should I not do with pointers.

Comment: do you know where exactly you have the access violation? 0xcccccccc seems like uninitialized value

Comment: Isn't the file, that you open, a text file? I believe it is. And if so, you should treat it as text file, not as binary one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to take the address of your fields:

```
fin.read(( char* ) &kfstruct.num_views, sizeof( int ) );
                  ^^^
```

[*As an aside, note that it's better from a maintenance point of view to do `sizeof(kfstruct.num_views)`.  So if the type ever changes, your code will still work.*]

Comment: You and Armen both wrote the same answer except for the brackets. Is there any difference with and without brackets?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
( char* ) kfstruct.num_views
```

use

```
( char* ) (&kfstruct.num_views)
```

similarly in the other place.

otherwise you are writing to a location whose address is equal to the VALUE of your int. You don't want that. You want the address converted to `char*`. You take the address by '&' operator.

Comment: You and Oli both wrote the same answer except for the brackets. Is there any difference with and without brackets?

Comment: @zsero: No there isn't, but to my taste it is more readable an unambiguous with them. Just a matter of taste and style